# How to check if the context menu is open on Autodesk Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any way to check if the context menu is active (open)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code shows the status of the context menus

```
if (viewer.contextMenu.contextMenu.menus.length > 0)
return true; // is active
else 
return false; // is not active
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `open` property of `viewer.contextMenu.contextMenu` which is a boolean.